# Nonlinear global optimization algorithm that can use dynamic programming

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-programming, dynamic-programming

I've asked this question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706028/nonlinear-global-optimization-algorithm-that-can-use-dynamic-programming) 2 weeks ago, but, judging by zero response, that probably was the wrong forum. Therefore copying it here:

Let `F0,...,Fn` be functions with parameters `p0,...,pn` and `G` be a composite function. Say, for `n=3` `G(x)=F3(p3,F2(p2,F1(p1,F0(p0,x))))`.

I'd like to globally optimize the parameters `p0,...,pn` with making as few function calls as possible. There are several ways to optimize:

1) Ignore that `G` is a composition of `Fi`s, treat it as a blackbox with parameters `p0,...,pn`, and use any generic global optimizer.

2) Optimize hierarchically; for clarity let's assume `n=3`:

Loop A: Freeze parameters `p0,p1,p2` and optimize `p3` in isolation. because `G` depends only on `p3` and the output of prior functions that have frozen params I only have to evaluate `F3`; the outputs of other `F`s don't change between iterations.

Loop B: Freeze parameters `p0,p1`, change `p2`, and repeat the above loop A. Repeat for optimizing `p2`.

Loop C: Freeze `p0`, change `p1`, repeat loop B, thus optimizing `p1`.

Loop D: Obvious.

This "dynamic programming" approach would lead to optimizing `G` by, hopefully, making fewer iterations. I have a couple of questions though:

First, I'm not sure that such hierarchical optimization approach would lead to solution of the same quality as the generic "blackbox" approach. Has any research have been done regarding the quality of results produced by hierarchical versus blackbox optimization?

Second, are there any optimization packages available out there supporting hierarchical optimization like that? I'm aware of a few available generic blackbox optimizers (NLOpt, etc), but not generic hierarchical optimizers.

Comment: Dynamic programming (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) is something else, it's a specific technique. Same for hierarchical optimization. What you're describing sounds like much more like coordinate descent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent).